# Invalid URL message when uploading an image file using urllib2

Tags: php, python, image-uploading

I am trying to upload an image file to piczasso.com from python. My code is as follows:

```
import urllib,urllib2

url='http://piczasso.com/api_handler.php'
values = { 'data':open('./imagefile.jpg'),
           'tags':'',
           'size':'None'
}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url,data)
try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
        print response
except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print e.code
        print e.read()

print "done"
```

However,im getting "Invalid URL!" as the output. I am however able to upload the image using a php page as follows.

```
<?php

/* 

Simple sample script which uses Piczasso API

Documentation about PicZasso API can be found here: http://www.piczasso.com/api.php

*/



if(isset($_GET["image"])){

    /* API sends output in JSON format */

    $image = json_decode(rawurldecode($_GET["image"]), true);

    /*

    $image array includes information about the image URL and sample links to it:

        $image["direct"] = Image URL

        $image["thumb"] = Thumbnail URL

        $image["image_page"] = Link to image

        $image["bbcode"] = bbcode for forums

        $image["html"] = html code

    Sample table below with image links.

    */

    $image["html"] = str_replace("+", "&nbsp;", htmlentities($image["html"]));

    echo "

    <img src=\"{$image["thumb"]}\" alt=\"\" />

    <table>

        <tr><td>HTML for Websites:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"codes1\" value=\"{$image["html"]}\" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>IMG Code for Forums:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"codes2\" value=\"{$image["bbcode"]}\" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>URL for E-Mail:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"codes3\" value=\"{$image["image_page"]}\" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Direct Link for Layouts:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"codes4\" value=\"{$image["direct"]}\" /></td></tr>

    </table>

    ";

} else {

    if(isset($_GET["error"])){

    /* Possible errors. Complete error list: http://www.piczasso.com/api_errorcodes.txt */

        $errorcodes = array(

            1000 => "No image selected",

            1001 => "Image failed to upload",

            1002 => "Invalid image type",

            1003 => "Image is larger than 16MB",

            1004 => "Cannot read image info",

            1005 => "Upload failed during process",

            1006 => "Database error",

            1007 => "Banned IP"

        );

        echo $errorcodes[$_GET["error"]];

    }

    /* Sample upload form below. Image can be resized also by sending for example this kind of fields:

        <tr><td>Resize x:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"size_x\"/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Resize y:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"size_y\"/></td></tr>

    */ 

    echo "

    <form action=\"http://piczasso.com/api_handler.php\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\">

    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"MAX_FILE_SIZE\" value=\"99999999\" />

    <table>

        <tr><td>File:</td><td><input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Tags:</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"tags\" /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Resize:</td><td>

        <select name=\"size\">

            <option value=\"1\" selected=\"selected\" >None</option>

            <option value=\"2\" >100x75 Avatar</option>

            <option value=\"3\" >150x112 Thumbnail</option>

            <option value=\"4\" >320x240 Websites</option>

            <option value=\"5\" >640x480 For forums</option>

            <option value=\"6\">800x600 15-inch monitor</option>

            <option value=\"7\" >1024x768 17-inch monitor</option>

        </select></td></tr>

        <tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"send\" /></td></tr>

    </table>

    </form>

    ";

}

?>
```

What is the problem with my python code ?

Please help
Thank You

Comment: Are the HTTP requests from the python code and the PHP page the same? May be there is some header missing. You might want to check that.

Comment: Im passing the filename,tags and size value in the http request..is there anything else i need to pass ?

Answer (score 1):

In the PHP code, the form has options for image size. The values are numeric, while the displayed options are text. The value for 'None' is 1.

```
values = { 'data':open('./imagefile.jpg'),
           'tags':'',
           'size':'1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeff. I made that change but still getting 'Invalid URL !'

Comment: This doesn't help much, then, does it? :) I noticed something else. Check out my new answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib2_file
import urllib2

data = {
        'apikey': '**********************************—0',#your APIKey
        'imgurl' : "www.example.net/img/dog1.jpg",
         'catid','0',
        'subject':'',
        'labeland':'',
        'labelor':'',
        'labelnot':''
       }
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api0.example.com:/api/v1.0/apisim_search', data)
content = f.read()
print(content)
```

Comment: Try example above. It's from this site http://www.visualsearchapi.com . Full code link is here http://www.visualsearchapi.com/apiDoc/apiDoc?apiDoc=V . Good luck.

Comment: This isn't even syntactically valid python, in addition to lacking context